# Memory leaks in InkEdit control

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks

I can't destroy [InkEdit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0A86.png) without memory leaks. The Dispose method helps a little, but still, a lot of unmanaged resources are not freed.

```cs
            // Create 16 InkEdit components

            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
                {
                    var ie = new InkEdit { Left = x * 50, Top = y * 50, Width = 40, Height = 40 };
                    panel1.Controls.Add(ie);
                }
            }
```

#### The example was modified to dispose all controls correctly.

```cs
            // 46 MiB of leaked RAM after every Create/Dispose iteration

            while (panel1.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                var lastIndex = panel1.Controls.Count - 1;
                var control = panel1.Controls[lastIndex];
                panel1.Controls.RemoveAt(lastIndex);

                control.Dispose();
            }

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
```

**With GC.Collect:**

[image]

**Without GC.Collect:**

[image]

Full sample:
https://github.com/dermeister0/InkEditTest

Comment: `panel1.Controls.Clear();` won't dispose of anything, of course. The `foreach` loop where you call `control.Dispose();` is wrong, you cannot modify the collection you're iterating, you won't dispose of all Controls. It's still `Controls.Clear()` that *clears* the Controls collection. Use a backwards `for` loop (from `panel1.Controls.Count - 1` to `0`). You can call just `GC.Collect()` after the loop, it won't make much of a difference.

Comment: I guess that is not a leak. GC just keep the memory in use due to optimisations for future object instances allocation. Disposing and collecting is not means [releasing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#memory-release) the memory.

Comment: @aepot That code is really leaking: the OP is not disposing of those Controls (which really need to be disposed of), so the memory usage will increase, constantly. Anyway, the code requires just a little fix (already described).

Comment: @Jimi nope, GC will call finalizers for all `IDisposable` objects automatically. I hope that class is properly implemented even if it has unmanaged resources inside. As result, there will be no leaks. Anyway, the memory screenshots and provided in the question information doesn't related to the leaks. I know that some .NET classes can leak in some rare cases but this one is common case which wouldn't cause a real leak. I suggest OP to learn more about Garbage Collection in CLR.

Comment: @aepot The implementation of that Control is not available, so you need to test it. I tested it. The Control is leaking *heavily* if not disposed of correctly. `GC.Collect()` won't do anything here. It may be because it *inherits* the native COM object, but I'm not interested in further investigations. The WPF control works well.

Comment: @Jimi _The foreach loop where you call control.Dispose(); is wrong, you cannot modify the collection you're iterating, you won't dispose of all Controls._ - wrong. `Dispose()` doesn't do with collection anything. It even doesn't do anything with object, it just releases unmanaged resources inside. You may run that snippet and ensure that `foreach` will iterate it properly without any Exception.

Comment: @aepot I already mentioned, I tested it. The loop is wrong, no questions in that, you cannot dispose of a collection of controls like that. Test it yourself, you'll see. I don't know what the internal `Dispose` method is doing, but calling it is clearly required. When you do (correctly), the memory usage won't increase (except the first *warm up*, which is to be considered *normal*)

Comment: @Jimi i agree that disposing controls before removing it from visual tree is not a thing to do. Thus if you know how to implement it properly, show us. I'm not a Winforms guy, I live in WPF Universe. I know that Winforms Designer implements `Dispose` for `Form` in case you add some `IDisposable`s there. It should work properly with memory.

Comment: @aepot You can remove controls from *the visual tree* (this is WinForms, WPF concepts don't apply, almost anywhere). Not just *can*, that's what you **have** to do. `Controls.Clear()` doesn't dispose of Controls, just removes the reference from the collection. You use it only when you're managing a collection of Controls yourself, adding and removing them from a container. The matter here is quite simple, this: `foreach (Control control in panel1.Controls) { control.Dispose(); }` is wrong, you cannot modify the collection you're iterating, nothing to do with WinForms, just plain mistake.

Comment: @aepot *You cannot modify the collection you're iterting* clearly means that when you dispose of a Control, you also remove it from the `Controls` collection of the parent Container, thus changing the collection. That's how it works.

Comment: @Jimi technically `Dispose()` doesn't remove the control from collection it has the other purpose. But ok, let it be.

Comment: @aepot *Technically*, this is exactly what it does and also what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Jimi
*You cannot modify the collection you're iterting clearly means that when you dispose of a Control, you also remove it from the Controls collection of the parent Container, thus changing the collection.*
Thanks, I have modified the code. It's still leaking unmanaged memory though. Yes, it's COM-based control.

Comment: As mentioned, I've tested your demo. With the simple change described (backwards loop, to effectively dispose of those Control - remove `Controls.Clear()` after the loop. If you leave `GC.Collect()` after, you'll see that it doesn't *collect* anything). The memory in this case increases when you first add new Controls, slightly (some KB) when you dispose of the existing and add new Controls. This is normal, that app is not using much memory (28MB on 64Bit). BTW, you appear to have added a reference to the 64bit `Ink` assembly, but the Project is setup to `Prefer 32Bit`. Correct that.

Comment: *If you leave GC.Collect() after, you'll see that it doesn't collect anything).*

It collects something for sure, you can see it on graphs. It adds not "some KBs" but ~480 MB after 10 runs.

*BTW, you appear to have added a reference to the 64bit Ink assembly*

It's MSIL assembly (AnyCPU 64-bit preferred). I don't why the reference receives AMD64 platform. Switched the project to x64 platform to resolve it.

Comment: If *~480 MB after 10 runs* are added, then you're still not disposing of those controls correctly. Show the code you're using.

Comment: The code is in the question, I've updated it.

Comment: `for (int i = panel1.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { panel1.Controls[i].Dispose(); } GC.Collect(); // <= Optional`. Nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Jimi. It does not resolve the issue though. 1,412 MiB leaked after 30 runs. I believe the root cause is inside InkEdit control.

Comment: I added an object pool to reuse the controls.

Comment: See the animation [here](https://imgur.com/a/ZK1Iioh), it speaks for itself (enlarge the Image to see it better). Note that the method I described, to dispose of the Controls, can be seen right below the Form, in the code window. The Memory usage doesn't increase at all, except, as mentioned, the first time the collection of Controls is created. This is normal behavior. If your results are different, then you're doing something wrong, something that you're not showing here or in the demo.

Comment: It's funny. Maybe we have different library versions. Here's my video: https://imgur.com/a/VSKRiv7 Code version: https://github.com/dermeister0/InkEditTest/commit/c00739ca6c28e1e488b3ca7f791a60c1c7a17ac1 Library: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Ink\6.1.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Ink.dll, Microsoft.Ink, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Comment: If that's the code you're using (in the GitHub repo), then of course it won't work, I've already described what's wrong with that kind of code. Use the code I posted (exactly how I posted it). The library version and bitness is the same.

Comment: *If that's the code you're using (in the GitHub repo)* I've updated the code on GitHub. *If so, what Timer?* Thread.Sleep(1000)

Comment: Well, the code I'm referring to is this: `for (int i = panel1.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { panel1.Controls[i].Dispose(); } GC.Collect();`. That's all you need (`GC.Collect()` is still optional). I don't see anything like it in your repo. I think we're done here.

Comment: It's c00739ca6c28e1e488b3ca7f791a60c1c7a17ac1 changeset I mentioned before. I assigned a branch name to avoid confusion: https://github.com/dermeister0/InkEditTest/blob/normal-dispose/src/InkTest/Form1.cs#L32

Answer (score 0):

I used [SimpleHelpers.ObjectPool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleHelpers.ObjectPool/) package to reuse the controls.

```cs
SimpleHelpers.ObjectPool<InkEdit>.MaxCapacity = 16;
```

```cs
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                SimpleHelpers.ObjectPool<InkEdit>.Clear();

                components?.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
                {
                    InkEdit ie = SimpleHelpers.ObjectPool<InkEdit>.Get(() => new InkEdit());

                    ie.Left = x * 50;
                    ie.Top = y * 50;
                    ie.Width = 40;
                    ie.Height = 40;

                    panel1.Controls.Add(ie);
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnDisposeAndClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = panel1.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var control = panel1.Controls[i] as InkEdit;
                SimpleHelpers.ObjectPool<InkEdit>.Put(control);
            }
        }
```

[image: Memory Usage with Object Pool]