# Memory Leak When using InkEdit control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, memory-leaks

We have a Windows Forms application that uses the Microsoft InkEdit control. This has not been a problem for 15 years. Worked fine with windows 7, 8 and 10. However, a recent windows 10 update has introduced a memory leak when this control is called.

There was a similar question on Stack Overflow:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63645140/memory-leaks-in-inkedit-control]

We have implemented those solutions into our code however we still have the memory leak.

Analysis seems to indicate the the windows DLL mshwLatin.dll is leaking memory.

I am showing a simple example to duplicate the problem. Again, occurs on somewhat latest Windows 10. Have a window call this window and then close it. My sample app starts at 4MB and grows to over 100MB after opening and closing 7-10 times.

Looking for a solution to the memory leak if there is one or how best to report this to Microsoft.

```vb
Imports Microsoft.Ink  

Public Class Form2  
    Dim inkfield As New InkEdit  
    Dim inkfield2 As New InkEdit  
    Dim inkfield3 As New InkEdit  
    Dim inkfield4 As New InkEdit  
    Dim inkfield5 As New InkEdit  

    Public Sub New()  

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.Controls.Add(inkfield)
        Me.Controls.Add(inkfield2)
        Me.Controls.Add(inkfield3)
        Me.Controls.Add(inkfield4)
        Me.Controls.Add(inkfield5)
        inkfield.Location = New Point(10, 10)
        inkfield2.Location = New Point(10, 40)
        inkfield3.Location = New Point(10, 70)
        inkfield4.Location = New Point(10, 100)
        inkfield5.Location = New Point(10, 150)
        inkfield.Height = 24
        inkfield2.Height = 24
        inkfield3.Height = 24
        inkfield4.Height = 24
        inkfield5.Height = 24
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This is no longer being supported so really shouldn't be used in new code. As to your problem from the docs a Warning "To avoid a memory leak you must explicitly call the Dispose method on any InkEdit object to which an event handler has been attached before the object goes out of scope."

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/ms552265(v=vs.90)

Comment: @Mary Very true, and Roger in general anything which implements IDisposable should be disposed when finished with it. `Public Class Ink Implements ICloneable, IDisposable`

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  In my actual code we do dispose of the object before closing the window.  This still leaves a memory leak.  Also did this in the sample provided and still causes a memory leak.  MARY: Can you please point out where this is no longer supported and what is to be used in it's place.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work or not for you, but you can try it, not in the same situation but it worked for me and I still use it. This reduce the size of memory used by the application. It's easy to create and test.

1. create a class with name clsMemory and insert this code:

   ```
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

    Public Class clsMemory

    <DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint:="SetProcessWorkingSetSize", SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Friend Shared Function SetProcessWorkingSetSize(ByVal pProcess As IntPtr, ByVal dwMinimumWorkingSetSize As Integer, ByVal dwMaximumWorkingSetSize As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint:="GetCurrentProcess", SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Friend Shared Function GetCurrentProcess() As IntPtr
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        Dim pHandle As IntPtr = GetCurrentProcess()
        SetProcessWorkingSetSize(pHandle, -1, -1)
    End Sub
    End Class
   ```
2. Create a button btnCleanMemory on your form and insert this code:

   ```
     Dim MemClass As New clsMemory()
     MemClass = Nothing
   ```

It's a long shot but just click on that button when there is a huge amount of memory used by the application to see if it will work for you.